# Would an advanced alien civilization use radio waves to communicate?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, radio

When SETI tries to look for aliens, they always try to catch the echos of radio waves sent out from alien civilizations. But would an advanced civilization even bother to use radio waves? Are there hypothetical communication systems that are superior to radio waves? Or are radio waves truly the best way to go?

Comment: Depends on whether you're looking for deliberate attempts to communicate, or for accidental radio-frequency emissions.  For the latter, consider how Earth's accidental emissions are decreasing due to cable vs broadcast TV, internet over fiber optic cables, low-powered IC devices, and the like.

Comment: Duplicate? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/would-advanced-extraterrestrial-life-really-use-radio-signals-as-the-way-to-comm/34935#34935

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would advanced extraterrestrial life really use radio signals as the way to communicate over interstellar distances?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/would-advanced-extraterrestrial-life-really-use-radio-signals-as-the-way-to-comm)

Comment: This has been nominated for reopening, but nothing about the question has changed and both Rek and @Frostfyre are correct that this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Kudos to Justin for mentioning entanglement](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/104224/21222). His idea about using quantum physics and more advanced, hitherto unseen technologies is right on spot.

I'll just add another option that I think is in the same spirit: [tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon). They are theoretical particles with a rather interesting set of properties:

- They travel faster than light. They can never slow down to light speed;
- Moreover, the less energy they have, the faster they go. When their kinectic energy approaches zero, their speed tends to infinity;
- Due to their FTL nature, they may also allow communication backwards in time.

Infinite speed makes for faster communication than sending regular particles through wormholes. Sending messages to the past makes it even faster than entanglement, though in sort of a cheating way.

Comment: I'd advise against actually using tachyon communications. While a civilization using it is an interesting theoretical question, it would be too different from anything people have experience of to actually convey understandably. So this is strictly "incomprehensible elder gods from beyond the stars" stuff. Of course, if you need a reason why your aliens are incomprehensible to humans, giving them access to this tech and working out the consequences is a good start.

Comment: @villeniemi it has been used many times in science fiction. Some famous examples range from the good (Old Man's War, by John Scalzi) to the bad (Into the Black, by Evan Currie). Any true sci-fi reader will be familiar with how bizarre the behavior of such comms is.

Comment: If some of these posters were around when Asimov wrote his foundation and robot series, they would never have been written. These were written before we had computers. The positronic brain came well before integrated circuits. Sci-fi leads physics, it is not supposed to be hampered by it,

Answer (score 0):

If they were really advanced, the answer would probably be 'no they would not bother with electromagnetic communication'. Any electromagnetic communication would be spurious noise, some form of an anachronism. It really is, for interplanetary communications, quite limited and inefficient. In perhaps another century, humans could very well be remarking at our dependency on it, the same way we remark on our former dependency on the 'pony express' and snail mail.

It is to be expected that their physics text book is much, much thicker than ours.

With the advances that are being made in quantum physics, there is every indication they would use such principles as entanglement (principles that we are only guessing at), for instance. The notion that some will posit - that such communication is impossible - only slows down our discovery of it.

**Edit** 
See for instance [Scientists Achieve Direct Counterfactual Quantum Communication For The First Time](https://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-have-achieved-direct-counterfactual-quantum-communication-for-the-first-time)

**Edit** 
And another article [Nil Communication: How to Send a Message without Sending Anything at All](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/nil-communication-how-to-send-a-message-without-sending-anything-at-all/)

I have absolutely no doubt that there are quantum fields that we can not even speculate on. We just discovered the Higgs field, for instance, a previously  unimagined and unimaginable field previously. There is no justifiable reason to believe that it will be the last one discovered.

Even the Higgs field itself, if it could somehow be manipulated, could lead to some new form of communication.

As Einstein himself called it. 'spooky action at a distance'. Just because Einstein had no use for it, and could not comprehend such a thing, does not make it impossible.

Comment: Why would those be better forms of communication?

Comment: @pyrulez entanglement may allow for communication across vast distances which is cheaper than EM radiation in terms of power, and which cannot be intercepted (as far as we know).

Comment: I thought entangled communication was considered impossible, e.g. the [no-communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem), and [physics.se's own conclusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78118/quantum-entanglement-as-practical-method-of-superluminal-communication).

Comment: @Renan Not only that, but if you have FTL communication, your story also becomes a time travel story.

Comment: As @rek says, quantum entanglement does not allow for information transfer, and therefore cannot be used for communication. You're misapplying firm physics principles in a hand-wavy way.

Comment: @rek You thought wrong. The advanced physics quantum computing lab at the University of Waterloo is already doing it,

Comment: @HDE 226868 Tell that to the people at the quantum computing lab at the University of Waterloo, who are already doing it. It is now reality,

Comment: Down voting the truth and quantum physical reality does NOT make it any less factual. You might not LIKE it, but it IS reality - or, rather, quantum reality.

Comment: @JustinThyme That article isn't the same thing as what you're claiming; it does *not* use entanglement. Additionally, the conclusion is highly dependent on the interpretation of the results, and a single experiment that has not been replicated by anyone else is not a good reason to claim that decades and decades of science is wrong.

Comment: @JustinThyme What's with the attitude? This is stack exchange, not reddit.

Comment: To quote the Nil Communication article, "Information moves slower without particles than with them." As long as that remains true it means this form of communication – if it works as presented – is less useful than radio waves in most circumstances.

Comment: @ rek It just means our physics book isn't thick enough yet. When LED screens first came out, the failure ate was 9 out of ten. So when you bought one, you paid for ten. The process was refined,

Comment: @ HDE 226868 And there is a lot of Einstein that has not been validated by ANY experiment. Your point?

Comment: @JustinThyme My point is that you're misinterpreting an article and drawing incorrect conclusions. You're making unsupported claims.

Comment: @HDE 226868 My point is that the physics textbook is doubling in size every ten years, and anyone using the book as it was in 1990 is using a very thin book, indeed. There was about 150 years between Newton and the ideas that led to his demise. It has now been 150 years from these ideas. It is time to move on.,

Answer (score -3):

An advanced alien civilisation would likely have a more advanced means of communication than radio waves. In order to become an advanced civilisation however, they've likely passed through a period where (like us) they've relied on radio waves for their own communication.

We as a species engage in archaeology to understand the past; we can hope that they might look at the radio spectrum as we do, looking for younger races. This of course assumes that their technical development has occurred in parallel to ours. It's possible that they've not discovered radio waves during their development, in which case they wouldn't think to look for them any more than we look for signals in gravitational waves, for example.